# Getting elements from array by class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of list items that i get like this:

```
var searchResultItems = $(resultContainerId + ' li');
```

The search result items can have different classes. How can i get all items of a certain class from the searchResultItems? Im looking for something like:

```
var highPriorityItems = searchResultItems.find('.highPriority');
```

I know find() does not work in this situation because it goes through child elements. I am hoping there is something similar what im looking for.

Comment: You are looking for `.filter`. It's not that hard to find by browsing the manual.

Comment: Thanks! I tried googling several times on different versions of this questions title. Want to make this an answer?

Comment: I don't see a real point to it, but I did in case you want to accept an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.filter` method can do exactly what you want if substituted for `.find` in your example.